# Drawing a hoof-like structure

Tags: tikz-pgf

The right and left curves are more wider in their radius than the drawing but the two sides are symmetrical with a rectangular top and base. [image]

Comment: Given that you've received answers to several similar questions, perhaps you would like to try adapting one of those solutions yourself rather than simply posting another draw-it-for-me without even the basic document framework required for an answer? At the very least, you could link to the questions you've got solutions to so that people do not have to start by duplicating work that has already been done, albeit not by you.

Comment: Near exact duplicate question from the same OP. BOO! HISS!

Comment: @Harish Kumar: not clear how you saw question as asked before and marked as duplicate. The two drawings are very different, it is self evident

Comment: @jayr: The philosophy and method are same. If you want I can vote for re-opening.

Comment: @jayr I have reopened the question since you were not happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple code:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=.2cm,inner sep=0pt,line width=.7pt,line join=round]
\draw (-60:3)arc(-60:60:3) (-60:5)arc(-60:60:5);
\draw [rotate=180](-60:3)arc(-60:60:3) (-60:5)arc(-60:60:5);

\draw (60:3)--(60:5)node[above]{c}--coordinate[label=above:b](b)(120:5)node[above]{a}--(120:3)--coordinate(b')(60:3) 
(240:3)coordinate(m')--(240:5)coordinate[label=below:m](m)--(-60:5)coordinate[label=below:h](h)--(-60:3)coordinate(h')--(240:3);

\draw(b)--(b');
\foreach \pos/\lett in {0/i,1/j,2/k,3/l}
\draw ($(h')!\pos/3!(m')$)--(h-|{$(h')!\pos/3!(m')$}) node[below]{\lett};

\foreach \ang/\lett/\lettt in {-36/g/q,-12/f/p,12/e/o,36/d/n}{%
\draw (\ang:3)--(\ang:5) node at (\ang:5.2) {\lett};
\draw[rotate=180] (\ang:3)--(\ang:5) node at (\ang:5.2) {\lettt};}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}  




\begin{document}

\def \f {3}
\def \r {1.5}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick, blue!85] 


\foreach \a in {10,30,50,310,330,350}
\draw 
( {\f*cos(\a)}, {\f*sin(\a)} ) -- ( {(\r*\f)*cos(\a)}, {(\r*\f)*sin(\a)} );

\foreach \a in {130,150,170,190,210,230}
\draw 
( {\f*cos(\a)}, {\f*sin(\a)} ) -- ( {(\r*\f)*cos(\a)}, {(\r*\f)*sin(\a)} );

\draw ( {\f*cos(50)}, {\f*sin(50)} ) -- ( {\f*cos(130)}, {\f*sin(130)} );
\draw ( {\r*\f*cos(50)}, {\r*\f*sin(50)} ) -- ( {\r*\f*cos(130)}, {\r*\f*sin(130)} );

\draw ( {\f*cos(230)}, {\f*sin(230)} ) -- ( {\f*cos(310)}, {\f*sin(310)} );
\draw ( {\r*\f*cos(230)}, {\r*\f*sin(230)} ) -- ( {\r*\f*cos(310)}, {\r*\f*sin(310)} );



\draw ({\f*cos(310)}, {\f*sin(310)}) to[bend right=51] ({\f*cos(50)}, {\f*sin(50)});
\draw ({\r*\f*cos(310)}, {\r*\f*sin(310)}) to[bend right=52] ({\r*\f*cos(50)}, {\r*\f*sin(50)});

\draw ({\f*cos(130)}, {\f*sin(130)}) to[bend right=51] ({\f*cos(230)}, {\f*sin(230)});
\draw ({\r*\f*cos(130)}, {\r*\f*sin(130)}) to[bend right=52] ({\r*\f*cos(230)}, {\r*\f*sin(230)});


\draw ( 0, 2.3 ) -- ( 0,3.45 ) node[above] {?};
\draw ( .8, -2.3 ) -- ( .8,-3.45 )node[below] {j};
\draw ( 1.92, -2.3 ) -- ( 1.92,-3.45 )node[below] {i};
\draw ( -.8, -2.3 ) -- ( -.8,-3.45 )node[below] {k};
\draw ( -1.92, -2.3 ) -- ( -1.92,-3.45 )node[below] {l};

\node [right] at ( {\r*\f*cos(50)}, {\r*\f*sin(50)} )   {?};
\node [right] at ( {\r*\f*cos(30)}, {\r*\f*sin(30)} )   {d};
\node [right] at ( {\r*\f*cos(10)},  {\r*\f*sin(10)} )   {e};
\node [right] at ( {\r*\f*cos(350)}, {\r*\f*sin(350)} ) {f};
\node [right] at ( {\r*\f*cos(330)}, {\r*\f*sin(330)} ) {q};
\node [right] at ( {\r*\f*cos(310)}, {\r*\f*sin(310)} ) {h};

\node [left] at ( {\r*\f*cos(130)}, {\r*\f*sin(130)} )  {?};
\node [left] at ( {\r*\f*cos(150)}, {\r*\f*sin(150)} ) {v};
\node [left] at ( {\r*\f*cos(170)}, {\r*\f*sin(170)} ) {p};
\node [left] at ( {\r*\f*cos(190)}, {\r*\f*sin(190)} ) {o};
\node [left] at ( {\r*\f*cos(210)}, {\r*\f*sin(210)} ) {a};
\node [left] at ( {\r*\f*cos(230)}, {\r*\f*sin(230)} ) {m};
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Minor detail, but I'd guess that the thing which looks like a "v" is actually a "q", since the OP appears to have been labeling everything alphabetically moving clockwise, and "q" would make sense. And since the sequence starts with "d" and there are 3 unknowns at the top, I'm guessing it would be safe to assume they're "a", "b", and "c".

Comment: @ParthianShot, nice catch. I was thinking to include the letters in the loop but since some letters are missing, I ignore it. lol. Left them as an exercise to the OP. :)